# Capturar valor de un input de un modal PHP

Tags: javascript, php

espero y puedan apoyarme.

Tengo un modal, pero en base a mis necesidades, tuve que capturar el id_clientes desde la vista de clientes, y pasarlo a una pantalla modal para editarlo según mi necesidad.

Para resolverlo, lo que hice fue capturar ese Id con javascript y lo devolví a un campo input (hidden) dentro del modal editar. Ahora necesito tomar ese ID para poder mandar a llamar al controlador y realizar una serie de acciones.

Como tomo el valor de ese campo input, dentro del mismo modal editar_clientes. Como ven en la imagen ya lo tengo incluso impreso en mi modal, pero no encuentro la forma de hacer referencia a su valor. El código esta escrito en PHP. Es decir, lo quiero hacer es asignar una variable  con el valor del input tipo hidden.

Si observan en la imagen siguiente, tengo ya el id, solo me falta asignar ese valor en una variable php ($variable) y seguir adelnte con los siguientes métodos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero y me puedan ayudar.

Saludos,

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español!  Tu pregunta, tal como está formulada, no sigue los criterios adecuados para ser considerada aceptada en este sitio. Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y luego puedes [edit] esta pregunta e incorporar un [example] que nos ayude a ayudarte, pues tal como está ahora podriamos estar filosofando sobre lo que no vemos de tu código durante horas.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.